# On smooth extensions of functions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, linear-algebra, ds.dynamical-systems

Let $f(x) = \left(I - \hat{n}\hat{n}^T \cdot\textbf{1}_{\vec{n}^TAx \geq 0}\right)Ax$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, $A$ is a (symmetric) $d\times d$ positive definite matrix, $\hat{n}$ is an arbitrary unit vector and $\textbf{1}$ is the indicator. Let $S = \{x:\hat{n}^Tx \leq 0\}$ and consider $f:S \to S$. I want to understand whether or not $f$ has a smooth extension $\tilde{f}:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$. Are there any references? The reason I am asking is because I want to use stable-manifold theorem on $f$ but $S$ is a manifold with boundary.

Thank you!

Comment: I know there exists Whitney's theorem but i am not sure if it is applicable because of the boundary.